# Line integral definition and mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

If you take a look at the [derivation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Derivation) of line integral article, you can see the following statement:

> $$I = \lim_{\Delta s_i \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) \, \Delta s_i. \tag{1}$$
> We note that, by the mean value theorem, the distance between
> subsequent points on the curve, is
>
> $$\Delta s_i = |\mathbf{r}(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf{r} (t_i)| \approx |\mathbf{r}' (t_i)| \,\Delta t.$$
>
> Substituting this in the above Riemann sum yields
>
> $$I = \lim_{\Delta t  \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i))|\mathbf{r}'(t_i)| \, \Delta t \tag{2}$$

I'm wondering how to more rigorously derive eq. 2 from eq. 1, because I have a few doubts about the method used above:
Note that it is a vector valued function. The mean value theorem article that it refers to doesn't really give any explanation, it even states there is no direct analog of mean value theorem for vector valued function (actually there's one involving an inequality).

> There is no exact analog of the mean value theorem for vector-valued functions.

I will be grateful for a clear explanation as I'm not a math expert.

Comment: $r(t)$ is usually a parametric function in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: An exact equivalent to the MVT in the complex field is impossible: there is no order in the sense there is in the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first clearly state all assumptions made in the article:

- $U\subset\mathbb R^m$ is an open set, $C\subset U$ is a subset of $U$
- $\mathbf r: [a,b]\to C$ is a bijective, parametrized curve that is also continuously differentiable. Note that this implies that $C$ is compact.
- $f:U\to\mathbb R$ is a function such that $f\circ\mathbf r$ is absolutely Riemann  integrable over $[a,b]$. It follows that $(f\circ\mathbf r)\cdot\lvert \mathbf r'\rvert$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$.
- For $n\in\mathbb N$, we define $\Delta t=\frac{b-a}n$. For $i=1,2,\dots, n$, we define $t_i=a+(i-1)\Delta t$ and $\Delta s_i = \lvert\mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t_i)\rvert$.

Now we notice: $$\Delta t\to 0\iff n\to\infty$$ and $$\Delta s_i \to 0\iff \mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)\to 
\mathbf r(t_i)\overset{\mathbf r\text{ bijective}}\iff\Delta t\to 0\iff n\to\infty.$$

So we need to prove the following

**Theorem.** We have $$\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) \Delta s_i=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i))|\mathbf{r}'(t_i)| \Delta t.}$$

*Proof.* Notice that, by definition of the derivative, we have $$\mathbf r'(t_i)=\lim_{\Delta t\to0} \frac{\mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t_i)}{\Delta t}.$$

It follows that $$|\mathbf r'(t_i)|=\left|\lim_{\Delta t\to0} \frac{\mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t_i)}{\Delta t}\right|=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\left|\frac{\mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t_i)}{\Delta t}\right|=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\overbrace{\left|\mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t_i)\right|}^{\Delta s_i}}{\Delta t},$$

where I have used continuity of the absolute value in the second equality and the fact that $\Delta t>0$ in the third equality.

Indeed, this means that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $\Delta t<\delta$, we have

$$\big\lvert\Delta s_i-\lvert \mathbf r'(t_i)\rvert\Delta t\big\rvert\le\varepsilon\Delta t.$$

Since $\Delta t\to0\iff n\to\infty$, this means that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have \begin{split} \left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) \Delta s_i-\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i))|\mathbf r'(t_i)|\Delta t\right|
&=\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) (\Delta s_i-\lvert\mathbf r'(t_i)\rvert\Delta t)\right\rvert
\\& \le \sum_{i=1}^n \Big\lvert f(\mathbf{r}(t_i))\Big\rvert \Big\lvert\Delta s_i-\lvert\mathbf r'(t_i)\rvert\Delta t\Big\rvert
\\&\le\varepsilon\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert f(\mathbf r(t_i))\rvert \Delta t}_{\text{Riemann sums of } \lvert f\circ\mathbf r\rvert}
\\&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \varepsilon \int_a^b \lvert f\circ\mathbf r\rvert.\end{split}

It follows that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) \Delta s_i-\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i))|\mathbf r'(t_i)|\Delta t\right|\le\varepsilon\int_a^b \lvert f\circ\mathbf r\rvert,$$ which immediately implies that $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) \Delta s_i-\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i))|\mathbf r'(t_i)|\Delta t\right|=0}$$ which proves the Theorem. $\square$

Comment: Thank you. Could you say a word about why the mean value theorem was mentioned in the article? Maybe it shouldn't be used in that context if this is a vector valued function? Especially that the mean value theorem article it linked to explicitly stated there is no such theorem for vector valued functions.

Comment: @user4205580 The MVT can be applied *for each coordinate separately*: Indeed, we have by the MVT: $$\mathbf r(t_i+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t_i)=(r_1(t_i+\Delta t)-r_1(t_i),r_2 (t_i+\Delta t)-r_2(t_i),\dots, r_m (t_i+\Delta t)-r_m(t_i))=\Delta t\cdot(r_1'(t_i+\xi_1),\dots, r_m'(t_i+\xi_m))\approx \Delta t\cdot \mathbf r'(t_i),$$ where $r_1,r_2,\dots r_m$ are the (cartesian) coordinates of $\mathbf r$ and $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_m\in[0,\Delta t]$

Comment: However, my proof uses only the definition of the derivative without referring to the MVT

Comment: Ok, thank you. "for all $\Delta t<\delta$, we have 
$\big\lvert\Delta s_i-\Delta t|r'(t_i)|\big\rvert\le\varepsilon.$" - sorry for asking, but didn't you forget about denomiator here? In the next step you just multiply both sides by $\mathbf r(t_i)\Delta t$ and sum over all $i$, right?

Comment: ...and used the triangle inequality.

Comment: @user4205580 1. We directly have $$\left\lvert\frac{\Delta s_i}{\Delta t} -\lvert r'(t_i)\rvert\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$ and I multiplied both sides with $\Delta t>0$. EDIT: You are right, I forgot about putting $\Delta t$ on the right-hand side, but this is just a typo as I used the correct bounds in the rest of the argument (also, the typo is now corrected  ) 2. Yes, for the bound on the difference of the two sums I used the triangle inequality

Comment: @user4205580 Also, I have added some more detail on the triangle inequality

Comment: Thanks. Going back to your comment about MVT applied for each argument separately - my biggest concern is using $\approx$ symbol inside limit expressions, because it might lead to wrong conclusions, even though it worked fine in this particular case. That's why in my opinion the derivation could be a bit more rigorous in this article. What do you think?

Comment: Could you explain why did you assume that $f$ is continuous? I cannot see it anywhere in the article.

Comment: @user4205580 They assume that $f$ is a scalar field and from Wikipedia's article on the scalar field: "it is typical in mathematics to impose further conditions on the field, such that it be continuous or often continuously differentiable to some order." However, if you don't like this assumption, notice that the proof also works verbatim if $|f|$ is bounded on $C$. I think that the argument can be modified also such that we can completely drop the continuity assumption and replace it just with $f$ being integrable on some suitable set, but I am not sure about that

Comment: @user4205580 With my new argument, $f$ need not be continuous anymore

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the small delta argument at the end. Why is it even used there? If you take the limit of both sides of the previous inequality, you will get the integral on the right and the inequality still holds.

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure if $\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) (\Delta s_i-\lvert\mathbf r'(t_i)\rvert\Delta t)\right\rvert
 \le \left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf{r}(t_i)) \Big\lvert\Delta s_i-\lvert\mathbf r'(t_i)\rvert\Delta t\Big\rvert\right\rvert$ inequality is true in your new argument. Take $n=2$, and $f(\mathbf{r}(t_1)) = 1$, $\Delta s_1-\lvert\mathbf r'(t_1)\rvert\Delta t = 2$, and $-1$, $-2$ respectively for $i=2$. After performing the summation the left side of inequality equals $4$, the right equals $0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user4205580 You are right, I have made some small edits accordingly